# Boostrap, divs under each other with image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to get some divs under each other with bootstrap. I have this for html:

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>
    <div class="linkblok hidden-xs" ><a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div>
    <div class="img-responsive"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a></div>
    <div class="linkblok hidden-xs" ><a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div>
    <div class="img-responsive"><a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a></div>        
</div>
```

this is my css:

```
.linksblok div {
    margin:20px;
    display:inline-block;   
}

.linkblok {
    background-color:#68b022;
    padding:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #68b022;
    margin:-1px;
}
.linkblok.active {
    background-color:#3d6f1c;
}
.linkblok a,.linkblok a:active,.linkblok a:visited {
    color:#ffffff;
```

I also added a screenshot how it looks like now.

but so the lowest green block has to be on the same line as the upper green block. and the images have to be too exactly under each other on the same line.

[image]

Thank you

it looks now like this, if I do:

```
.linksblok div {
    margin:20px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
}
```

[image]

If I do it like this:

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-5"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div>
        <div class="img-responsive col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-5"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div> 
        <div class="img-responsive col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2"><a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a></div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Then it looks like this:

[image]

In the begin it has to be like this:

[image]

but so if you make it smaller then it has to be under each other, but alligned(the green boxes).

I try it like this:

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
<div class="row">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="linkblok hidden-xs" ><a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="linkblok hidden-xs" ><a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But then still it looks like this:

[image]

I have it now like this:

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
```

and it almost works. if you make it smaller it renders correct. But if you have full screen it looks like this:

[image]

I have it now like this:

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>
    <div class="row">

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12">


        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div>

        <div class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div> 

        <div class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a>
        </div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But still the last logo is under the rest and not on the same line

I have it now like this:

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>


    <div class="row">



        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs  col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div>


        <div class="img-responsive  col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}"  alt="logo sfg"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs  col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div> 

        <div class="img-responsive  col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a>
        </div>


</div>
</div>
```

But still the last image goes under the three other images and not on the same line

Comment: try using display:block on all the divs, then they will take full width of the parent block.

Comment: You are using bootstrap, so you can use the bootstrap grid to align your content in a repsonive way by using rows and column spans.

Comment: `.img-responsive` needs to be applied to `<img>` as it then scales to its parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should use the Bootstrap grid system. Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

It should be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 center-block">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row top-buffer">
        <div class="col-xs-8 center-block">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want responsiveness you should change/add classes to the col-xs-6 div's.

Here's a CodePen that shows how it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwmgm.

EDIT:

Edited the CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwmgm. I believe this is what you want to achieve!

```
<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="img-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I see in your example if I make the screen smaller, the four images become two images. How can that be?

Comment: It's because these images have a fixed width & height. I now created a class '.image-responsive' which has width: 100% and height: 100%. The images scale with the browser size now. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwmgm. If you need me to work it out in your own code, let me know!

Comment: ok. THank you. But yes, can you work it out with my code. Because this is with a extra green block. That makes it different. Thank you

Comment: Do you need the green blocks to disappear on small screens? (I saw you added hidden-xs)

Comment: Yes, indeed. First it is on one row(the two green blocks and the images) if you make it smaller it is has to be on the image I posted(under each other) and if you make it real smaller the green blocks dissapear. Thank you

Comment: This should do it I think: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwmgm EDIT: If you want them to stack under each other at medium screens you should change 'col-sm-6' to 'col-sm-12' and add 'col-md-6'. EDIT2: I would highly suggest you to read the bootstrap documentation about the grid system and other components over here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

Comment: Oh, but you didnt end some div block

Comment: Please check my post, I added a new snippet.

Comment: Thank you. But you dont close the div? Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Closed it now.

Comment: It almost works. Thank you. I edit my post. Can you maybe look at it

Comment: I think that's because of the fixed width of your container. Try to change col-sm-8 to col-sm-12 and remove col-sm-offset-2. 
You should play around with these values yourself too. It will make you understand the grid system.

Comment: I realy tried everything. But still the last logo is not on the same line, but under the rest

Comment: You could try to change the class 'img-responsive' to 'image-responsive' (this is a default bootstrap class) or create a class 'img-responsive' with width: 100% and height: 100%.

Comment: You should also change col-sm-4 to col-sm-6, so the image and the green block make 12 columns together on small/medium devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use display block and than define the width of the blocks as per your need.

```
.linksblok div {
    margin:20px;
    display:block;   
    width:150px;
}
```

See if this what you need.

Comment: Thank you. But it looks like now this(see image). and it has to be like the first image. But just that the under green block is on the same line as the upper green blcok

Answer (score 0):

```
height:200px;width:50px;
```

please check the demo i have shared on jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharD/pq0rpwdL/1/)

Comment: Thank you. But what exacyly did you changed? Because I dont see height:200 px in your fiddle

Comment: Thank you for your answare. I will check it monday.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap you could fix this by wrapping the divs which belong to each other in a row-class and then add some spans to align them. Like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="text-center linksblok">
                <p><strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div><br/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-5"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div>
            <div class="img-responsive col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="logo sfg"/></a></div>
        </div><br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="linkblok hidden-xs col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-5"><a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a></div> 
            <div class="img-responsive col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="logo vlietland"/></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

You can of course play around with the size of the columns, but I think that this will help you to align your content.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8juL8a0/2/)**

Comment: I mean, how to make the green blocks the same? Thank you

Comment: You can check this Fiddle -- Also edited my code a bit. https://jsfiddle.net/p8juL8a0/2/

Comment: HI Abr, but this are two images. And have not the same length. I describe four units: two green blocks and two images. Like in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try doing as below:

`<div class="text-center linksblok">
    <p>
       <strong>Zoekt u specifieke informatie over een behandeling of uw ziekenhuis?</strong>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="linkblok hidden-xs right" >
                 <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="img-responsive">
                 <a href="http://www.sfg.nl">
                       <img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/SFG logo.png')}" alt="logo sfg"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="linkblok hidden-xs" >
                 <a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/">Bekijk de site van &gt;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="img-responsive">
                 <a href="https://www.vlietlandziekenhuis.nl/">
                       <img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Vlietland logo.png')}" alt="logo vlietland"/>
                 </a>

            </div>

        </div>
     </div> 
</div>`

add this in css -

`.right { text-align: right; }`

hope this helps!

--

**UPDATE -**

Check this [Sample jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ravk/jf4wkn23/2/) here.

Comment: sorry, but this makes it realy a mess.

Comment: have added a JSFIDDLE please check, If I'm understanding your question correctly. This is how you want?

Comment: I only see two images. NOt the green boxes. See my screenshot

Comment: If I'm looking correctly at my fiddle, it displays both the green boxes. Check the screenshot [http://www.screencast.com/t/fVy4jwHGcT4] of fiddle what I see at my end, isn't it the same for you?

Comment: Thank you. But I cant see the screenshot

Comment: But now the greenbox is above the logo. And not like in my screenshot

Comment: Ah, not sure why not! Please check now --- http://www.screencast.com/t/fVy4jwHGcT4

Comment: Do you want green boxes to be below of respective logos?

Comment: Do you see my screenshot? it has to be like that:

Comment: Alright, I've updated the fiddle. Hope it will fit to your purpose now. Thanks!

Comment: this is not what it has to be. Look at my screenshot. The greenboxes under eacht other with right the correct logo's

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this without using so much `css` you can read [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You should start mastering this method for it is very powerful when is comes to creating responsive layouts in `Bootstrap`.

You can see this [JSFIDDLE SAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/9wkk44r9/) I created. Just play around with the values and `css`. Hope it helps. Cheers.